Is it good practice to substitute an organization SSL certificate into an HTTPS connection?
I run a scientific web site, call it site.org, that is mirrored at three locations, all listed in DNS as site.org so that clients will choose a specific mirror at random.  The individual mirrors are server1.site.org, etc.  The LetsEncrypt certificate covers site.org plus the mirror names.  All of the mirrors are inside universities that are donating bandwidth; I don't have the funding to pay for the bandwidth myself.
One university, univ.edu, recently decided that for "security control of https communication" (their words) all sites inside their network should be behind their *.univ.edu wildcard certificate.  Their implementation is that at the firewall, when they see a port 443 connection, they intercept the SSL handshake and substitute their own certificate.  My server never sees the certificate handshake.  The client browser sees the *.univ.edu certificate and rejects it because it doesn't cover site.org.  I asked for my server's IP to be whitelisted for passthrough, and they said doing so was "not possible".
To me, substituting their certificate for mine looks like an adversary-in-the-middle attack.  To be fair, I don't know if they're actually sitting there and monitoring traffic, but I don't see anything to prevent them from doing so.  I don't give a hoot about the monitoring for my own purposes (everything on the site is public anyway) but it just seems like a Bad Idea to me even though it makes it much easier for them to manage certificates for sites inside univ.edu.
So: is it normal for large organizations to use an AITM approach to managing certificates?  Is this really just because they want to snoop on all (incoming, but not outgoing) connections?  Are there reasons I haven't though of for why this is a Bad Idea?
Fundamentally I'm looking for strong arguments I can use to talk them out of their position.  If they won't bend, I fear I'll have to shut the mirror down, which would be sad for my users because that mirror has much better bandwidth to the continent it is located in.  (Alternative suggestions would be appreciated, though!)

It is perfectly normal that an organization (university, company, ...) wants control over the traffic inside their network. This includes inspection and filtering the traffic for security and compliance, maybe with some exceptions for privacy. After all it is their network and they are responsible for it.
It is also common that mirror sites hosted by third parties are not all subdomains of a common domain name, but instead have domains reflecting the organization where they belong to. I don't know what makes it impossible for you to follow this approach.

The individual mirrors are server1.site.org, etc. The LetsEncrypt certificate covers site.org plus the mirror names.

I'm not sure if this means that all these sites use the same certificate, including the same private key. In this case the private key is distributed not only over multiple servers but these servers (or at least the infrastructure hosting the servers) are also managed by different organisations. This increases the risk of compromising the private key. Better use separate certificates.

Thanks, that's helpful.  However, in this case some people who look up site.org in DNS will be randomly directed to the IP of server1.univ.edu, which will then (appear to) present the *.univ.edu certificate instead of the site.org certificate.  I don't see a way to work around that.  (Also, is it possible using letsencrypt to have multiple certificates that all claim to be site.org?  I could certainly set up each mirror to ask for a different certificate, but server1 would have to say it was site.org,server1.univ.edu and server2 would then say it was site.org,server2.site.org, etc.)

@gkuenning: "some people who look up site.org in DNS will be randomly directed to the IP of server1.univ.edu" - from this statement I assume that you use DNS based load balancing between the various mirrors - which is a particular implementation choice you have taken for load balancing but not the only option and maybe not even the best option since selection of server is not done on features like current load or available bandwidth - and the servers you use seem to have different capabilities here. So maybe you should rethink this approach.

@gkuenning: "Also, is it possible using letsencrypt to have multiple certificates that all claim to be site.org?" - in principle yes, i.e. multiple valid certificates for the same domain are possible. Validation might conflict though with the way you manage the domain with DNS based load balancing, since HTTP challenge in Let's Encrypt expects to reach the actual server after DNS lookup which asked for the certificate for the domain. But you might use DNS challenge.

Thanks again, Steffen.  Yes, I use DNS load balancing (it turns out that that's just fine for my situation).  But you've given me the information I need to understand the problem and to come up with a solution.
